# Class table inheritance in Yii framework using MySQL views

Tags: php, mysql, yii, class-table-inheritance

I would like to implement class (multi) table inheritance in Yii but i found it very difficult, so i planned to use the approach of MySQL view.

Here is an example of my tables and classes:

**CmsAd** is a table that inherits all the fields included in **CmsContent** table:

```
CREATE TABLE `CmsAd` (
  `Id_CmsAd` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Image` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Id_PrdClass` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Id_PrdCatalog` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id_CmsAd`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `CmsContent` (
  `Id_CmsContent` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `ModifiedBy` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ModifiedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(99) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Subject` varchar(350) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Text` longtext,
  `KeyWord` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Code` varchar(340) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id_CmsContent`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**CmsAd_View** is a MySQL view that contains the join of those two tables :

```
CREATE VIEW `CmsAd_View` AS SELECT `CmsAd`.*, `CmsContent`.* FROM `CmsAd` LEFT JOIN `CmsContent` ON `CmsContent`.`Id_CmsContent` = `CmsAd`.`Id_CmsAd`;
```

Here are the models of those tables :

```
class CmsAd extends CActiveRecord {

    public function tableName() {
        return 'CmsAd_View';
    }
}


class CmsContent extends CActiveRecord {

    public function tableName() {
        return 'CmsContent';
    }
}
```

Notice that the table name of **CmsAd** is the view **CmsAd_View**.

Now I would like implement the CRUD the **CmsAd**. It's ok with **find()** method because it retrieves from the view **CmsAd_View**.

My Problem is with **insert()** and **update()** methods where we have to insert and update both tables **CmsAd** and **CmsContent**.

Is there any one who tried to implement the view approach of table inheritance in Yii ?

Comment: Yii simply generates insert/update sql. Is it one to one ralation? Have you tried [updatable views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html)?

Comment: Yes it's one to one. I tried to insert directly in the view but it shows the following error: #1471 - The target table CmsAd_View of the INSERT is not insertable-into.